lodash-es vs lodash bundle size comparison
There's a project I'm currently working on which uses regular lodash library. For now we use 3 util functions cloneDeep, isEmpty, and get.
Currently import statements are like so import util from 'lodash/util' so nothing is bloated.
I've read that lodash-es is better than lodash due to treeshaking but it seems like lodash-es bloats more.
I deleted lodash and installed lodash-es and started to use import statements like so
import { util } from 'lodash-es'.
And compared both bundle sizes lodash vs lodash-es and it seem that lodash-es bloats more then lodash.

vs


If you really care about the extra 3KB why not just copy the functions into your codebase? That means one less dependency and it's just 3 functions that you likely never have to touch again. 2 of the functions you shared are probably 1-liners in modern javascript.

Hey @Evert thanks for answering. Im actually planing to use more lodash util function soon, this is why I started doing this comparison initially. Im wondering maybe when we will have 30+ util usages it will make an impact.

Again, if you care about this kind of payload you should reconsider lodash. Almost everything that library does is now either built-in or was never needed! Good luck!

Thnx I will take in consideration, Yet I still wonder why lodash-es bloats more than lodash?

Sounds interesting. Can you provide a [mre] or your usage for this?
